# spring class not found when it exists

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I'm getting an exception that "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" does not exist in my WebContent\WEB-INF\spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml file. I have the spring-webmvc 4.1.2 dependency added and I the class exists in my maven dependencies so it's as though it isn't seeing those classes from my maven dependencies?

```
    <bean id="HandlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using eclipse, try clean project, and then clean Tomcat directory.
Also make sure that maven dependencies are present in WEB-INF/lib, if not, this is configurable from Project Properties > Deployment Assembly

Comment: It appears there are no spring jars in the WEB-INF/lib folder, here is my deployment assembly: http://i.imgur.com/OogS59X.png is this configuration correct?

Comment: Yes, its correct, just try Project>Clean... After that open servers view in eclipse, right click on tomcat and click Clean...

Comment: Project->clean worked thanks! Any reason behind why this would work?

Comment: It has to do with eclipse-tomcat integration. When a dependency is added to the webapp, this doesn't get synchronized with the tomcat deploy directory, e.i dependency doesn't get copied to WEB-INF/lib, so the developer have to click Tomcat>Clean... which redeploys the webapp.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have multiple versions of `spring-webmvc` on your classpath as dependencies of other direct dependency. Call `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=spring-webmvc` to see how many versions of the library you have and exclude older versions.

Or, if you are using Intellij, enable the maven plug-in, generate diagram, search with Ctrl-F for `spring-webmvc` and where you have older dependency right click on it and choose `exclude`. Probably eclipse has similar functionality too.